# dependent: :destroy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following situation:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  after_create :create_profile
  after_create :programstart

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :weights, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :programstarts, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :user_nutrients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :nutrients, through: :user_nutrients, dependent: :destroy


  private

  def programstart
    Programstart.create(:user_id => id)
  end
end
```

**nutrient.rb**

```
class Nutrient < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, uniqueness: true

  has_many :user_nutrients
  has_many :users, through: :user_nutrients
end
```

**user_nutrient.rb**

```
class UserNutrient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :nutrient
end
```

For profile, weights and programstarts the `dependent: :destroy` works. All the associated database entries are removed when I delete the user. However, for `user_nutrients` the `dependent: :destroy` is not working. After deleting the user these entries are stil there.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What's the error message ?

Comment: There is no error message. I delete the user from the console, all dependent records are deleted except the ones in the user_nutrients table.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post - 
http://makandracards.com/makandra/32175-don-t-forget-automatically-remove-join-records-on-has_many-through-associations
you should do the following:

```
has_many :user_nutrients
has_many :nutrients, through: :user_nutrients, dependent: :destroy
```

and in nutrient.rb

```
has_many :user_nutrients
has_many :users, through: :user_nutrients, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Tried this - records are still there.